# Correct way of nesting Riverpod providers watch calls inside widget

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

calls What is the correct way of nesting Riverpod providers watch inside the build method?
Currently I have this code:

```dart
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final position = ref.watch(positionProvider);

    return position.when(
      data: (position) {
        final getNearbyHospitalsProvider =
            ref.watch(getNearbyHospitalsUseCaseProvider(position));
        return getNearbyHospitalsProvider.when(
          data: (hospitals) => Column(
```

The getNearbyHospitalsUseCaseProvider needs the position from the positionProvider.

Is this code right? I don't know if using `ref.watch` inside the data function is correct or not. Its like the example on the Riverpod docs that states `The watch method should not be called asynchronously, like inside an onPressed of an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles.`

Moreover I don't know if calling the nested watch would rebuild the widget returned by the data function or not. Maybe I have to wrap the returned widget inside a Consumer o extract it to another ConsumerWidget to make it work without errors?

Comment: Looks legit to me.  It's not within a callback... it's executed directly while build is active.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract this part into a separate ConsumerWidget.

```
class NearbyHospitalWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NearbyHospitalWidget({
    super.key,
    required position,
  });

  final position;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

  final getNearbyHospitalsProvider =
          ref.watch(getNearbyHospitalsUseCaseProvider(position));

  return getNearbyHospitalsProvider.when(
          data: (hospitals) => Column( ... // and beyond
  }
}
```

Why? If `getNearbyHospitalsUseCaseProvider` has additional dependencies, it will only rebuild `NearbyHospitalWidget` if they are changed. Otherwise, in your case the entire widget is rebuilt.